# expressJS rendering login bootstrap modal if action is not authenticated

Tags: express, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing an expressjs/ejs app which is using Twitter Bootstrap 3 for web pages. I have used Bootstrap Modal for login. I have included the modal in the header section so it is available for every webpage. However, if a user has not logged in, he needs to be authenticated before performing certain actions on the app. I am using a middleware function to determine whether a user is logged in, however if a user is not logged in, I need to redirect him to home page and initiate the login model directly. I am not sure how I can initiate the bootstrap modal from server side. Any thoughts?

I need to be able to do:

```
response.render('/home#loginModal');
```

That way user is directed to home page and is given a chance to login.