# How to show alert message when credentials are incorrect in node.js | express

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to NodeJS and Express, I'm trying to make a login-registration page for understanding the basic concepts. My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316989/expressjs-rendering-login-bootstrap-modal-if-action-is-not-authenticated) but there is no solution posted. I'm using a [bootstrap modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h) for login. What I did to display login modal :

1. Created an empty modal div in the header file so that it is available through the application

```html
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Loaded modal when clicked on `login`  link

```html
<a href="/login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Login</a>
```

And at `server.js` file

```js
var reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views/pages/userLoginPopup');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render(reqPath, {isvalid: true}); //isvalid variable is for displaying error
});
```

3. Created modal body in another `.ejs` file

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <%if(!isvalid){%>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">

        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'">&times;</a>
        <strong>Incorrect credentials!</strong>
    </div>
    <%}%>

    <form action = "/login" method="POST">

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span>
            <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required type = "text" name = "ccname"/>
        </div> <br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
            </span>
            <input placeholder="ID" class="form-control" required type = "text" name = "ccid"/>
        </div> <br />

        <input type = "submit" value = "Login" class="btn btn-md btn-success btn-block">

    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

4. Now when user enters incorrect credentials the alert is not shown in the modal instead the page is loaded(as shown below)
   [image: loginIssue]
5. In the `server.js` file retrieving the form data and checking in DB  for authentication, if the user is authenticated it is redirected to the `home` page and if not then current page is rendered with another value for `isvalid` flag.

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

    var lname = req.body.ccname;
    var lid = req.body.ccid;

    service.loginUser(lname, lid, function (err, result, privilege) {
        if(err){
            res.render('./pages/error', {errorName: err});
        }else {
        if(result){
            req.session.name = lname;
            req.session.uid = lid;
            req.session.privilege = privilege;
            res.redirect('/'); //home.js
        }else {
            res.render(reqPath, {isvalid: false});
        }
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong can anyone help? I know that I need to pass the modal id where the modal is needed to be load(as done while loading the initial login modal) but I don't know how to do that while submitting form. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:** This is what I'm getting when loading modal
[image: loginModalPopup]

**Update 2:** Project structure

```
projectName
|
---- routes
    |
    --- userLogin.js
|
---- views
    |
    --- pages
         |
         --- userLoginPopup.ejs
    |
    --- partials
         |
         --- header.ejs
|
---- app.js
```

Comment: Can you specify what do you expect to happen and what actually happens? I'm trying to understand from the question, but is hard. Are you able to load the page with the error message or not?

Comment: I'm trying to show the alert message if user had entered incorrect credentials. What I'm getting is shown in the screenshot I added in the question(point 4).. and what I expect is some what like [this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=error-alert-message)

Comment: @Diksha probably you did not included bootstrap library(css & js file, js file required for modal) as I can see your screenshot UI. You should check Bootstrap path if you have already added

Comment: @ArifKhan the bootstrap is included but is not showing on this render(point 4), added the screenshot now

Comment: I'm trying to show the updated screenshot with [this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=error-alert-message) error @ArifKhan

Comment: @Diksha you did not show where you are including modal file, I mean `views/pages/userLoginPopup`

Comment: it is in the same directory with `app.js`